# Is it correct to say: "A, B, then C" instead of "A, B, and then C"?

Tags: grammaticality, prepositions

I sometimes hear people append the last item in an ordered list (especially a step-by-step procedure) with only "*then*" (without the preceding "*and*"). For example:

> Go to google.com, enter *miserable failure*, then click **I'm Feeling Lucky**.

I understand the saying, but in written form, it seems incorrect. Is it correct English to omit "*and*" in this case?

Comment: You can separate any or all of the steps using either or both of *and* and *then*. It's really just a matter of style with very little significance - except that if you use neither, even before the *last* step, it can sound a bit brusque.

Comment: From Jules Verne's "Journey to the Center of the Earth"
"They went down the crater, then they followed the tunnel, then they reached the center of the Earth."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This reference](http://grammar.ccc.commnet.edu/grammar/conjunctions.htm) puts it best:

> This is a **comma splice**, a faulty sentence construction in which a
>   comma tries to hold together two independent clauses all by itself:
>   the comma needs a coordinating conjunction to help out, and the word
>   *then* simply doesn't work that way.

A practical piece of advice for remembering coordinating conjunctions from the same site:

> It may help you remember coordinating conjunctions by recalling that
>   they all have fewer than four letters. Also, remember the acronym
>   **FANBOYS**: For-And-Nor-But-Or-Yet-So. Be careful of the words *then* and *now*; neither is a coordinating conjunction, so what we say about
>   coordinating conjunctions' roles in a sentence and punctuation does
>   not apply to those two words.

So, to answer the question -- no, the sentence needs to read:

> Go to google.com, enter miserable failure, *and* then click I'm
>   Feeling Lucky.

Comment: Hmm, I wonder what pseudo-grammarian down-voted my answer?

Comment: It was me (no, not I) because this is an arbitrary prescriptivist viewpoint that has no basis in fact.

Comment: @JonPurdy: Fair enough. I don't necessarily dispute down-votes; I just appreciate the courtesy of being informed of the reason for a down-vote. I hang out on these sites to learn, after all.

Comment: Ditto, and downvotes are nothing personal coming from me, which doesn’t seem to be the case for everyone—when I get downvoted, it’s usually because I’m being controversial.

Comment: @JonPurdy: You are also the one who downvoted my reply, ain't you?

Comment: @Tim: Ah sho do be. With mah apologies.

Comment: @Gnawme I came across your answer while researching the then/and then question. Using "and then" instead of just "then" with an independent clause makes sense, but do you consider "and click" an independent clause? Is it that "you" is the understood subject of the second clause? For example, "I run and jump." I consider this one clause with a double predicate. Would "I run, then jump."  be wrong?

Comment: [Related](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/598864/2085).

Answer (score 5):

I'd originally posted this as a comment. But because I disagree with both answers here, I'll post it as an answer so anyone who agrees with me can upvote it.

You can separate any or all of the steps using either or both of *and* and *then*. It's really just a matter of style with very little significance - except that if you use neither conjunction, even before the last step, it can sound a bit brusque.

I'll also add that personally I think it's stylistically odd to *reduce* the conjunctive forms as you list the steps. For example, I don't much like...

> *Do step1, and then step2, then step3.

...it's more common to *increase* them...

> Do step1, step2, then step3  (or ...*step2,* **and** *step3*).
>
> Do step1, then step2, and then step3.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can coordinate all three without *and*.  This is called *asyndetic coordination*, which means that there's no overt coordinator present:

> *Syndetic* coordination: A, B, **and** C
>   *Asyndetic* coordination: A, B, C

In your example, the third conjunct contains the adverb *then* functioning as a connective adjunct:

> [ Go to google.com ]<sub>A</sub>, [ enter miserable failure ]<sub>B</sub>, [ **then** click I'm Feeling Lucky ]<sub>C</sub>.

You could insert the overt coordinator *and* before C, or before both B and C.  But you don't have to.

---

When there's no overt coordinator, commas are generally required.  In the following example, I've omitted what would be the Oxford comma, making the sentence unacceptable:

> *Go to google.com, enter miserable failure then click I'm Feeling Lucky.

Compare this to one of the most famous examples of asyndetic coordination:

> I came, I saw, I conquered. 　 　 *(contains obligatory comma)*
>   *I came, I saw I conquered. 　　 *(missing obligatory comma)*

If *then* truly were a coordinator, we'd be able to join three items without an Oxford comma, or pair two items without any commas:

> I ate food, then I went to the store. 　 　 *(contains obligatory comma)*
>   *I ate food then I went to the store. 　　 *(missing obligatory comma)*

But we can't, so it's not.

---

Of course, this sort of coordination isn't always appropriate.  In particular, when the conjuncts seem only loosely related (or not related at all!), people are likely to notice how they're put together and call the resulting coordination a "comma splice".  To some people, the difference between asyndeton and a comma splice is whether or not they like the result:

> I came, I saw, I conquered.　　　　　　　　*(I like it, must be asyndeton.)*
>   <sup>??</sup>Computer games are fun, I'm hungry.　　*(I don't like it, must be a comma splice!)*

So use your own judgment.  If you're joining clauses that are only loosely related and you think they need an overt coordinator, put one in.  (Or don't coordinate them.)

Comment: So you're saying *then* is not a conjunction? And  *We ate, then we went home* is asyndetic?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, "then" is not a conjunction here, and it cannot be used alone without "and".

> Go to google.com, enter miserable failure, **and then** click I'm
>   Feeling Lucky.

If you don't want to use "and", then you can change the punctuation:

> Go to google.com. Enter miserable failure. **Then** click I'm
>   Feeling Lucky.

Comment: I don't see anything odd about *Do this, then that, then the other*.

Comment: Probably, because it is not uncommon in verbal communication.

Comment: But I'm guessing you still think it's grammatically incorrect and shouldn't be used in writing. I don't think that, obviously!

Comment: Yes, your guess is right. Although I am not a native speaker, this is what I learned from my old grammar books.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to propose a different example:

FOR EXAMPLE:
*First, let's go to the beach; then we can go shopping.*

In my example, the first clause is independent.  The second clause begins with "*then*" used as a conjunctive adverb.  Conjunctive adverbs require a semicolon preceding them because otherwise, this situation would be known as a comma splice.

To help me remember which ones are conjunctive adverbs, I either look it up, or else I remember that sentences can begin with conjunctive adverbs.

If my example were a command, it would be as follows:

EXAMPLE:
*First, (you) go to the beach; then (you) go shopping*.

My implied subject is still a subject, and these are still clauses, so the semicolon is still required.

[SOURCE](https://webapps.towson.edu/ows/conjunctions.htm#CONJUNCTIVE%20ADVERBS)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

"But this use of then as a coordinating conjunction is actually both widespread and widely accepted": From the The American Heritage Dictionary https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=then&submit.x=0&submit.y=0

> Sticklers for grammar sometimes assert that then is not a coordinating
> conjunction, and that the sentence She took a slice of pie, then left
> is thus incorrect; it must be rewritten as She took a slice of pie and
> then left, in which the then acts as an adverb and the halves of the
> compound predicate are linked by the coordinating conjunction and. But
> this use of then as a coordinating conjunction is actually both
> widespread and widely accepted; in our 2012 survey, more than three
> quarters of the Usage Panel found the sentence She took a slice of
> pie, then left completely acceptable.