# Are FANBOYS the ONLY coordinating conjunctions that can coordinate two independent clauses? Are there any others?

Tags: coordinating-conjunctions, independent-clauses, subordinators

I wanted clarification on exactly which coordinating conjunctions can take independent clauses.

This question rose when I looked up the definition of *because* in some dictionary. That dictionary said that *because* is a conjunction, but my grammar workbook claimed that a clause starting with *because* was an independent clause.

This was from a particular question on the workbook page, but considering the definition, I assumed that it's always going to be the case.

That surprised me, because I didn't really notice the difference between **independent** and **dependent** clauses. I mean, more accurately, I didn't really notice
the difference between **subordinating** conjunctions and **coordinating** conjunctions. What is that difference, particularly when clauses are involved?

I'm guessing that because the FANBOYS set (*for, and, nor, but, or, yet*, and *so*) are the only coordinating conjunctions in English, that therefore only they alone can take independent clauses if they start a sentence and that all other English conjunctions **besides** the FANBOYS set must only ever be subordinating ones and never coordinating ones.

Am I right or wrong?

Comment: [FANBOYS is a lie](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/598940/2085).

Comment: You're wrong. Forget the nonsensical FANBOYS. There are just four coordinators: "and", "or", "but" and"nor".

Comment: I think your grammar book is wrong; a clause starting with *because* is not independent.

Comment: If you have an actual question about whether a specific use of "because" is right or wrong, you should feel free to ask it (after checking for duplicates, etc). But your question as it stands is only going to get answers saying "ignore FANBOYS", which probably isn't helpful in your immediate problem.

Comment: I have attempted to clarify your question by editing it.  I wasn't always completely certain what you were saying, though, so if I've gotten anything wrong, do please feel perfectly free to edit it yourself to fix whatever that seems  off to you.

Answer (score 4):

The core of your question seems to be about how subordinating and coordinating conjunctions work with dependent and independent clauses.  Here's my take in a nutshell.
A subordinating conjunction is part of the dependent clause, and we can prove this by rearranging a sentence: an experienced speaker will intuitively move the conjunction together with the clause.  Here's an example:

- *We left the party because the house caught fire.*
- *Because the house caught fire, we left the party.*

Shifting from observations about structure to observations about meaning, we can see that the logic of the sentence changes if we put the subordinator in the wrong phrase: "The house caught fire because we left the party" is not the same as the earlier statements.

The classic coordinators (*and*, *but*, *or*, and *nor* – which is 'or' negated) don't work this way. These two sentences are basically equivalent:

- *We left the party and the house caught fire.*
- *The house caught fire and we left the party*.

True, a listener *might* make inferences about time and logic because of the order of the clauses, but the sentence does not *necessarily* express any implication of time, consequence, or causation through "and," and many grammarians will say that "and" is not part of either clause.

SO: bearing in mind that grammar is a contested field, let's take on the FANBOYS treatment.

Where things get sticky is with *for*, *yet*, and *so*.  'Yet' and 'so' are old adverbs that work as conjunctions, and 'for' is an old preposition that works as a conjunction – and there are some fuzzy boundaries between prepositions and adverbs, so we should expect complications.
The most important reason some people say they are not coordinating conjunctions is that, unlike 'and', 'but', and 'or'/'nor', they are clearly part of a clause.  We can't reverse clauses around them and preserve the same meaning; we can show that 'for' works a lot like 'because' with this example:

- *We ate, for the food was hot*.

is not synonymous with

- *The food was hot, for we ate*.

However, in MODERN English, we can't acceptably relocate the 'for' phrase to the beginning of the sentence:

- **For the food was hot, we ate.*

We see that these three words don't act like prototypical subordinators, either, which is the reason some people think of them (and class them)  together with the coordinators.

There are other differences, too: 'for', 'yet', and 'so' don't work in the same variety of settings as 'and', 'but', and 'or'/'nor' do; the latter can fit into all kinds of phrases. Also, 'yet' and 'so' still work as ordinary adverbs, and 'for' works as an ordinary preposition, which adds the to the confusion.

Basically, I don't consider 'fanboys' a useful categorisation for discussing syntax, even if it provides a rule of thumb for comma placement.  I'm also against being snarky about the issue, because it's genuinely confusing, and grandstanding about grammar is for people who sneer and ask little kids "I don't know, CAN you go to the bathroom?"  You know who you are. Repent and do better.

Comment: Hello, Ven Bede, and thank you for the answer. I've reformatted; bulleting isn't that easy on ELU, but does make things easier to see. // The Fanboys analysis has been refuted before on ELU, with references to the Brett Reynolds article and CGEL. And the very definition of 'dependent clause' is contested by some. // Other 'coordinating conjunctions' have been posited, including 'no more' ("They don't gamble, no more do they smoke"), and 'only' ("I would go, only I don't have time").

Answer (score 1):

> I'm guessing coordinating conjunctions are only FANBOYS and therefore only ones that can make independent clauses if they started a sentence? Am I right or wrong?

You are wrong even to think that "FANBOYS" is anything more than general guidance filled with ifs, buts, and exceptions.

I refer you to

[The Myth of FANBOYS: Coordination,Commas, and College Composition Classes](https://teslcanadajournal.ca/index.php/tesl/article/view/1092/911) Brett Reynolds (pdf download, but worth it...)

And this from [Right Touch Editing](https://www.righttouchediting.com/2020/06/18/the-trouble-with-fanboys/)

> FANBOYS is a mnemonic device to help students remember that the coordinating conjunctions are *for, and, nor, but, or, yet,* and *so.* It teaches that you should join two independent clauses with a comma and one of the FANBOYS.
>
> Trouble is, neither of these things is true.
>
> Brett Reynolds, an English professor at Humber College Institute of Technology and Advanced Learning, outlines the definition of a coordinating conjunction in “The Myth of FANBOYS: Coordination, Commas, and College Composition Classes” (PDF). According to Reynolds, coordinating conjunctions:
>
> Can’t occur next to each other: **Tom and nor Sara*
>
> Can’t be modified by another word
>
> Join two equal parts (constituents) of all sizes: words, phrases, and clauses
>
> Link two equal constituents that can usually be put in reverse order (are commutative): *Tom and Sara, Sara and Tom*
>
> As you can see from the table [in the linked article], only *and, but, nor,* and *or* meet all of the requirements for being a coordinating conjunction, while *for, so,* and *yet* meet only a few.

Comment: This is a comment and not an answer. The OP's question is what conjunctions there are other than FANBOYS, not whether or not all FANBOYS are coordinators. This seems to be deliberately missing the point.

Comment: @SeymourAzzes [A frame challenge is always a valid answer.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/263661/153355)

Comment: @tchrist But the OP's question is not an XY problem.  They are not asking why FANBOYS are coordinators or even how to do coordination with FANBOYS, in which case one would say that the premise is incorrect.  They are clearly exploring ways to combine clauses, specifically asking for ways that are beyond FANBOYS.  As Stuart F says in his above comment, such an answer "probably isn't helpful in [the OP's] immediate problem."  This feels more like kicking the new OP while they're down.